# AVR assembly on arduino uno, timer0 configuration?

Tags: assembly, timer, avr

I'm having a look at fiddling the registers in assembly programming for the AVR family, on an Arduino UNO board, with its standard bootloader (avra+avrdude).

I'm having trouble with the Timer0. I've reduced the problem to a short program wich is supposed to

- put a red LED on (on B5 = pin 13)
- configure the timer0 for normal mode, prescale 1024
- set the counter to 0
- enter a loop, and escapes when counter is over 200
- and then puts a green Led on (on B4).

Symptom: green led never turns on. With some other values than 200, turns on after a random duration (seconds).

Here is the code :

```
    .include "./m328Pdef.inc"

    .EQU ROUGE = 0b0100000   ; red
    .EQU VERT  = 0b0010000   ; green


main:   
    ldi r16,ROUGE+VERT      ; pins activated
    out DDRB,r16
    ldi r16,ROUGE           ; red on
    out portB,r16

    ;; configure timer
    lds r16,TCCR0B
    andi r16,0b11111000
    ori r16,0b00000101      ; prescale 1024
    sts TCCR0B,r16

    ldi r16,0       ; count is  0
    sts TCNT0,r16

loop:   
    lds r16,TCNT0            
    cpi r16,100
    brlo loop

    ldi r16,VERT     ; green on
    out PortB,r16

z:
    nop
    rjmp z
```

The same programs seems to work correctly with the Timer1 and its associated registers.

What's wrong?  Some interference with the bootloader?

EDIT the hex file :

```
:020000020000FC
:1000000000E304B900E205B900912500087F05600E
:100010000093250000E0009326000091260004369E
:0A002000E0F300E105B90000FECF97
:00000001FF
```

Compiled by : `avra bug0.asm`

Upload :

```
avrdude -q -V -D -p atmega328p -C /etc/avrdude.conf \
    -c arduino -b 115200 -P /dev/ttyACM0 \
    -U flash:w:bug0.hex:i
```

Comment: The code seems OK. Can you include the hex/srec/whatever you use to flash the board?

Comment: You can take a look at the source of Arduino UNO standard bootloader here: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot.c. The bootloader uses timer1, timer0 is left untouched.

Comment: edit : hex and compile/upload commands added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that constants: `DDRB`, `PORTB`, `TCCR0B`, `TCNT0`, etc. evaluate to **I/O addresses** of given SFRs (it's OK to use them with `in/out`) but you use `TCCR0B` and `TCNT0` with `lds/sts` which expect their operands to containt **data space addresses**.

The solution is to either use `in/out` with `TCCR0B` and `TCNT0` -- it's OK, because these registers belong to **I/O registers** (as opposed to **extended I/O registers** which must be accessed using their data space addresses):

```
    .include "./m328Pdef.inc"

    .EQU ROUGE = 0b0100000   ; red
    .EQU VERT  = 0b0010000   ; green


main:
    ldi r16,ROUGE+VERT      ; pins activated
    out DDRB,r16
    ldi r16,ROUGE           ; red on
    out portB,r16

    ;; configure timer
    in r16,TCCR0B
    andi r16,0b11111000
    ori r16,0b00000101      ; prescale 1024
    out TCCR0B,r16

    ldi r16,0       ; count is  0
    out TCNT0,r16

loop:
    in r16,TCNT0
    cpi r16,100
    brlo loop

    ldi r16,VERT     ; green on
    out PortB,r16

z:
    nop
    rjmp z
```

or to make this I/O addresses into data space addresses:

```
    .include "./m328Pdef.inc"

    .EQU ROUGE = 0b0100000   ; red
    .EQU VERT  = 0b0010000   ; green


main:
    ldi r16,ROUGE+VERT      ; pins activated
    out DDRB,r16
    ldi r16,ROUGE           ; red on
    out portB,r16

    ;; configure timer
    lds r16,TCCR0B+0x20
    andi r16,0b11111000
    ori r16,0b00000101      ; prescale 1024
    sts TCCR0B+0x20,r16

    ldi r16,0       ; count is  0
    sts TCNT0+0x20,r16

loop:
    lds r16,TCNT0+0x20
    cpi r16,100
    brlo loop

    ldi r16,VERT     ; green on
    out PortB,r16

z:
    nop
    rjmp z
```

For information on why you have to add `0x20` to these constants, see chapter 8.3 SRAM Data Memory on page 19 (especially the figure) of [m328p datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_complete.pdf) and [this bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/avra/bugs/35/).

---

Why the original code worked with timer1?

Timer1 registers are located in extended I/O space and `avra` probably substitutes their names with extended I/O space addresses (as they doesn't even have I/O space addresses).

---

Why the original code behaved erraticaly with timer0?

One can write `lds r16,TCNT0` as `lds r16,PINC+0x20`, reading the state of floating pins yields (more or less) random result.

---

To see what `avra` did with your code I used the command `avr-objdump -b ihex -m avr5 -D *.hex`, it shows what is actually written to the microcontroller.

For SFR addresses, see chapter 36. Register Summary of [the aforementioned atmega328p datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_complete.pdf).

You may need to install `avr-gcc` or `avr-binutils` to be able to use this command.

Comment: Ok it works now.  Thanks a lot for the explanations.

As I understand now, during the development of the AVR family, the bigger processors got more timers, but with addresses in different spaces than TIMER0. From examples for TIMER1 I (wrongly) supposed I could use the same instructions for  TIMER0.

Note to myself: consider reading the documentation.

Actually the names like TCNT0 are défined in the .inc file

     .equ TCNT0 = 0x26

so avra knows nothing about them. Just numbers.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you noticed that avra is "dead" since 2010. Alternatives are: avr-gcc assembler (well, it's quiet specific; it takes a while to learn the syntax) and inline assembly (again, it takes a while to learn how to use it properly).

Comment: Over decades I used a lot of different assemblers for various processors so syntax differences are not a problem. I don't intend to do serious programming in assembler anyway. 
As I understand, avra is atmel-compatible, so I expect examples from applications notes to be be usable. On the other hand, studying  `avr-gcc -S` output is a nice way to learn some tricks (and it produces avr-as compatible code).